# Why cannot addItem into QGraphicsScene from a QVector<QGraphicsItem>?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to undo or redo actions in a `QGraphicsScene` that is linked to a `QGraphicsView`: For that, I use `QGraphicsEllipse` (to draw points while moving and clicking on the `QGraphicsView`) in my `mouseMoveEvent` method, I push every `QGraphicsEllipse` in a `QVector<QGraphicsItem>`, and when the `QAction` "undo" is triggered the program must delete the last ellipses (determined number of ellipses) drawn in my `QGraphicsView` thanks to my `QGraphicsScene`.

When I clear my `QGraphicsScene` and try to add all `QGraphicsItems` that were pushed in my `QVector<QGraphicsItem>`, I got an error: my app goes down!

```
    if(index < historyIndex.size()){
        for (int i = 0; i < scHistory.size() - historyIndex[index]; i++){
            scene->addItem((QGraphicsItem*)scHistory[i]);
         }
        index++;
    }
```

```
    QVector<QGraphicsItem *> scHistory;
```

Comment: What is `_sceneHistory`? I think you need to show more context.

Comment: @drescherjm _sceneHistory is a QVector<QGraphicsItem *> that contains all the QGraphicsItem that were added to my scene.

Comment: Probably `QGraphicsItem` is freed twice. `QGraphicScene` takes ownership of Item when `addItem` is called. `QGraphicsScene::clear` removes and deletes items. So if you create QVector of QGraphicsItem once, and the code from your question (with adding and clearing scene) is called many times, you delete items many times what leads to crash. It is only my assumtption, because you didn't provide enough information to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QGraphicsScene::addItem` takes the ownership of the element added, check the [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addItem). It means that it is now in charge of destructing the element, which happens when you clear the scene with `QGraphicsScene::clear`. From that point on, your vector is full of dangling pointers.

One quick fix is to replace the call to `QGraphicsScene::clear` with a manual removal of items through [`QGraphicsScene::removeItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#removeItem), which doesn't destroy the item (it returns the ownership to the caller). Then, destroy only those elements that are actually out of the scene, and add back the rest. Another option, more efficient, is to remove only the elements you need, keeping the rest, so you also increase performance by avoiding add back a large number of items from the history.

Without a full knowledge of your code, the second options may be something like:

```
if(_indexHistoryRoam < _indexHistory.size()){
    // Remove only items beyond history
    const int range = _sceneHistory.size() - _indexHistory[_indexHistoryRoam];
    for (int i = range; i < _sceneHistory.size(); i++){
        scene->removeItem((QGraphicsItem*)_sceneHistory[i]);
        delete _sceneHistory[i]; // item must be destroyed to avoid a leak
     }
    _indexHistoryRoam++;
} else { // force removal of all elements
    scene->clear();
}
scene->update();
```